# Linking a DLLs in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, dll

I've already looked for solution, without a success.

I need to use a DLL supplied by third parties on Visual Studio 2013(running on (x64) Windows 10).
On machine there are both OpenCV 3.0.0 and OpenCV2.410 installed and working.

The DLL's author has provided a .lib file and He says that in order to use this DLLs in your project, you need to put some others OpenCV's dlls in the project folder( I've tried to put these DLLs in every project folder[yes I know, it has no sense, but after a lot of tries i've lost my patience])

What he supplies is an .dll and an example project( that doesn't work for me because it needs OpenCV2.1 and there are instructions needs to be translate in newest version [and I prefered don't translate nothing]).

The errors in this example project are of this kind:

- error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
- fatal error LNK1120: unresolved externals

The most of them are caused by the miss of OpenCV2.1, that I don't want to install, because I'll have to use it on a program using with OpenCV 3.0.0.

In the example project folder there are:

1. The upper mentioned .dll
2. A .lib file
3. The header file .h
4. These DLLs: cv210.dll, cxcore210.dll, highgui210.dll, ...(eg. cv210d.dll)

What I've done is this:

- A folder called "lib" where I insert all .dll, .lib, .h files.
- Put the "lib" folder in Project `properties>linker> General> Additional Library Directories`
- Writing the .lib file in `properties>linker> Input> Additional Dependencies`
- Put the 'lib' path`properties>C/C++>Additional Include Directories`[I know, this has no sense too]

I get these kind of errors:

- error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

I've tried `#pragma comment(lib, 'file.lib')` way too.

Someone can help me?

Comment: whats the name of the .lib file?  what kind of external symbols could not be resolved? opencv symbols? for opencv there is one .lib file for each .dll file. the .dll files aren't needed for linking.

Comment: Hi!
The .lib file is called ct1.lib
This is the complete report by OpenCV:
 `1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_track`
`1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_getRoi`
`1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_init`
`1>[path of executable] : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals`

Everyone of this is one function of .h file, ad it should be linked to .dll file

Comment: **[here](http://iris.usc.edu/people/medioni/tagntrack.html) is the code of that DLL.** It's a great work and I wish be able to use it in my project.

Comment: did you compile that DLL yourself? if a different compiler (version) is used, linking might not work.

Comment: I took that DLL from the aforementioned link. I have to use some function from it. Those functions seems to be declared in _.h_ . And the relative _.lib_ appear in the example project directory.

Comment: I cant download it atm, is there some information in the readme.txt how that dll was compiled?

Comment: It seems to have been used OpenCV2.1, VS2008. In "included list" are listed  DLL and OpenCV 2.1 DLLs too(It says: _"which are needed"_).
In _"How to Use"_ section, it's wrote something about the DLL and the fuction that are exported( there isn't wrote how). In second part of _"How to use"_ it's wrote : _"To run the example project, please make sure you add the ct1.lib to the visual studio directories as it is used to link with the project. Also, the openCV dlls (cxcore, highgui, and cv) need to be in the same directory as the project."_

Comment: maybe you need those declspec things... sorry I don't know how to use a visual studio 2008 dll in visual studio 2013.